# Livewire Internal Server Error 500 "/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable"

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-livewire

I am using livewire for my laravel project.
On the local server, I didn't get any error, but on the actual server, I got code 500.

I checked the logs in `../storage/logs`
and it says,

```
[previous exception] [object] (Exception(code: 0): The /var/www/html/<LARAVEL-project>/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable. at /var/www/html/<LARAVEL-project>/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Live>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by upgrading composer1 to composer2

[Official Composer Installation Guide](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

```
// Remove composer 1
sudo apt-get remove composer

// Follow the official composer installation guide
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

//make it global 
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
// or
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
// depending on the path you can check the path by using the command 'composer -V' before making it globally accessible

// lastly run compose update
composer update
```

then, livewire will be properly installed.
No more Server Error 500.